# How do I read and write to immutable blob storage in azure

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-log-analytics

I would like to put audit data in immutable blob storage. Is there a specific format that needs to be written in?

Also once written how do we query or see this data in case we have to look at the data.

Would log analytic be able to this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an immutable policy. You can do it using one of the management sdks or using the portal:

Create a blob container in any General Purpose V2 storage account. Then navigate to its properties and create a policy:

[image]

I used a legal policy, there is also a time based retention policy.

Offical documentation: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-immutable-storage#azure-portal)

You can read and write it using standard methods like (C#):

```
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudStorageConnectionString);
var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(StorageContainer);

var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("test");
blob.UploadText("Content");

Console.WriteLine(blob.DownloadText());

blob.UploadText("Modified Content"); // fails with a (409) conflict error with ErrorCode: BlobImmutableDueToLegalHold
```

Comment: even if we upload the text as log Will i be able to read it as part of log analytics when I need to investigate the audit

Comment: *even if we upload the text as log* -> I am not sure I understand what you mean with this.

Comment: what we will be writing to the immutable blob storage is some form timestamp based audit logs. which will grow to a vast amount. At some point in time we may want to investigate the audit like look at what had happened as a specific point in time. There should be a simple way to look at the data which is in blob storage. Do we need to write our own custom tool be able able to query this data?

Comment: Not necessarily, you could leverage [Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-unstructured-search) for example, especially if the content is json. Or you can use [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) to simply browse the file. Depending on the way those blobs are named you can filter them to quickly access specific blobs.